# Framed Knots -- Blackboard framing -- Ribbons

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, tikz-knots

I'm using Tikz to draw knots. I am wondering whether there is some way of drawing framed knots i.e. when you think of your knot as being made out of ribbon so that a Type I Reidermeister move induces a twist in it.

Edit: This is what I have. I would want to do the same thing for a ribbon so that you can see the thickness of the strand diminish because of the twist.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]
        \begin{knot}[
                consider self intersections=true,
                %  draft mode=crossings,
                ignore endpoint intersections=false,
                only when rendering/.style={
                %  show curve endpoints
                }
         ]
            \strand (2,0) 
                .. (2.2,1.5)
                .. (2.5,1.8)
                .. (3,1.5)
                .. (2.5,1.2)
                .. (2.2,1.5)
                .. (2,3);
        \end{knot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a minimal, but compilable example of what you've got so far and maybe an image of what you'd like to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As much to give a picture of what I think you're after as to show one way to achieve it.  This isn't automated in any way, and you can see defects where the lines join.  I'm not sure how automatic one could make this, particularly if you want the ribbon to be filled.  I think that my best suggestion would be to use the [`knots`](https://ctan.org/pkg/spath3) package for the majority of the diagram and then splice the twists in using a similar method to the below.  The code below could also be tidied up considerably with use of styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/427160/86}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[double=red,double distance=.5cm,line width=.1cm] (0,0) -- (5,0);
\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
\draw[double=red,double distance=.5cm,line width=.1cm] (0,-.5) .. controls +(0,2) and +(-2,0) .. (3,0) --  (5,0);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-3cm]
\draw[double=red,double distance=.5cm,line width=.1cm] (2,-.5) .. controls +(0,-1) and +(0,-1) .. (0,0) .. controls +(0,2) and +(-1,0) .. (3,0) --  (5,0);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-3cm,xshift=7cm]
\draw[double=red,double distance=.5cm,line width=.1cm] (-1,0) .. controls +(1,0) and +(0,.5) .. (2,-.5) .. controls +(0,-1) and +(0,-1) .. (0,0);
\draw[double=red,double distance=.5cm,line width=.1cm] (2,-.5) .. controls +(0,-1) and +(0,-1) .. (0,0) .. controls +(0,2) and +(-1,0) .. (3,0) --  (4,0);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-6cm,xshift=1cm]
\draw[double=red,double distance=.5cm,line width=.1cm] (0,0) -- (2,0) arc[radius=1,start angle=90,delta angle=-270] coordinate (a);
\draw[double=red,double distance=.5cm,line width=.1cm] (a) arc[radius=1,start angle=180,delta angle=-90] -- +(3,0) arc[radius=1,start angle=90,delta angle=-270] coordinate (b);
\draw[double=red,double distance=.5cm,line width=.1cm] (b) arc[radius=1,start angle=180,delta angle=-90] -- +(3,0);
\begin{scope}[yshift=-4cm]
\draw[double=red,double distance=.5cm,line width=.1cm] (0,0) -- (2,0) arc[radius=1,start angle=90,delta angle=-180] -- +(-2,0) coordinate (a);
\draw[double=red,double distance=.5cm,line width=.1cm] (a) arc[radius=1.5,start angle=270,delta angle=-180] .. controls +(1,0) and +(-1,0) .. +(5,-1) arc[radius=1,start angle=90,delta angle=-270] coordinate (b);
\draw[double=red,double distance=.5cm,line width=.1cm] (b) arc[radius=1,start angle=180,delta angle=-90] -- +(3,0);
\begin{scope}[yshift=-3cm,]
\path[double=red,double distance=.5cm,line width=.1cm] (0,0) -- (2,0) arc[radius=1,start angle=90,delta angle=-270] coordinate (a);
\draw[double=red,double distance=.5cm,line width=.1cm] (a) arc[radius=1,start angle=180,delta angle=-90] -- +(3,0) arc[radius=1,start angle=90,delta angle=-270] coordinate (b);
\draw[double=red,double distance=.5cm,line width=.1cm] (0,0) -- (2,0) arc[radius=1,start angle=90,delta angle=-270] coordinate (a);
\draw[double=red,double distance=.5cm,line width=.1cm] (b) arc[radius=1,start angle=180,delta angle=-90] -- +(3,0);
\begin{scope}[yshift=-3cm]
\fill[red] (0,.25) -- ++(2,0) .. controls +(1,0) and +(-1,0) .. ++(2,-.5) .. controls +(1,0) and +(-1,0) .. ++(2,.5) -- ++(2,0) -- ++(0,-.5) -- ++(-2,0) .. controls +(-1,0) and +(1,0) .. ++(-2,.5) .. controls +(-1,0) and +(1,0) .. ++(-2,-.5) -- ++(-2,0);
\draw[line width=.1cm] (0,.25) -- ++(2,0) .. controls +(1,0) and +(-1,0) .. ++(2,-.5) .. controls +(1,0) and +(-1,0) .. ++(2,.5) -- ++(2,0);
\fill[white] (3,0) circle[radius=.15] (5,0) circle[radius=.15];
\draw[line width=.1cm] (0,-.25) -- ++(2,0) .. controls +(1,0) and +(-1,0) .. ++(2,.5) .. controls +(1,0) and +(-1,0) .. ++(2,-.5) -- ++(2,0);
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: ribbon knots]

(This is a diagram I happened to have lying around, I used it [in an post on quaternions](http://loopspace.mathforge.org/HowDidIDoThat/Codea/Quaternions/#section.9).)

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted. I'll work through your code to figure it out. BTW, thanks for this whole knots package. It's really amazing.